# How to optimize a number of games with a limit set of second chances at guessing other options given probabilities?

Tags: probability, optimization, game-theory, optimal

Let's say I have a game with $M$ outcomes $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^{M}$ and I have a predictor $P$ that gives me probabilities for the outcomes of a game.

I now have $N$ independent games that I want to predict. The obvious choice for predicting the outcome would be to choose the outcome for each game with the highest probability given by $P$.

Now, I also have a total of $K$ extra chances to guess more outcomes of the $N$ games. I can spend them freely. For example, I can choose to guess an extra number of outcomes for the $n$-th game if I feel particularly unsure about that game and sure about all the others. Another alternative is to spend the guesses on a number of the games, for example, choosing a second outcome on $K$ of the $N$ games.

I have very little experience with game theory but is there an optimal strategy for choosing the $K$ options?

I have tried a number of strategies experimentally that have given me mostly similar returns in increased accuracy. They are

(1) Choose the second most probable option from the $K$ games with the lowest first choice probability.

(2) Choose the second most probable option from the games with the lowest KL-divergence compared to a uniform distribution over the options.

(3) Choose the $K$ options to maximize the sum of the probabilities for the K options. For example, if we have one game that is very certain and a game that is close to uniform we will choose to select the second, third, etc. options of that game instead of bothering with the very certain game.

(4) Pick the games with outcomes that $P$ has most errors in predicting. For example, $P$ might overly faulty in predicting outcome $O_i$ compared to the other outcomes thus we should insure against that option when picked by $P$. We learn what outcomes $P$ has the most difficulty with from the confusion matrix over the training data.